# ios : How to restrict airdrop to open my application only at the receiving side

Tags: ios8, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I've added airDrop feature in my application. I'm sharing audio file. But at the receiving end, 
the audio file should be handled by my application only. How to achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sharing an audio file that conforms to any of the public audio UTIs, you should instead define and add support for a UTI. Take a look at the [AirDrop sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/sc2273/Introduction/Intro.html) to see an example of this.